# Prism View loading in StockTrader sample

Tags: prism

I have been looking through the code and the pdf documentation and I can't find anything that indicates how the StockTrader sample application decides which view (PositionSummary or WatchList) should be displayed by default.

Can anyone explain how this is determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the stock trader RI uses its own custom behavior named **AutoPopulateExportedViewsBehavior**. This behavior is different from the one used by Prism as out of the box and is designed to work specifically with MEF. Along with the **ViewExportAttribute** it register the view in the container while also adding in to the corresponding region at start-up. You can find both of them in the **StockTraderRI.Infrastructure** project inside the **Behaviors** folder.

**Edit**: 
Maybe I misread the question. If you are asking how it's determined which view between the **PositionSummary** and **WatchList** views is shown first, there is no specific configuration for this. The order is related to what module is initialized first. If you were to move the **PositionModule** after the **WatchModule** in the bootstrapper, the **WatchList** would be the one being shown by default.

Comment: I never liked the StockTrader example for this reason. They consistently do things that are complicated and totally aside from the normal examples in the Prism book. Sometimes, there doesn't even seem to be any benefit other than to confuse the beginner.

Comment: Wow, I would have never expected that.  I did find all the things you mentioned and was still scratching my head as to how the positionSummary was activated because I couldn't believe that someone would think it would be a good idea to have the order of when a module was loaded determine what gets displayed.  Talk about a golden example of designing in "unintended consequences".  I would never expect the order of module loading to affect the configuration of an application.  Enable/disable features, sure.  I would have made this 'feature' more explicit in Docs.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation though.  I did verify that changing the order of modules does change the interface.